# go-remote is not downloading modules but goget.html

Tags: go, artifactory

I got 404 error when I `go get` through Artifactory remote repo.

```
$ go get -v github.com/pkg/errors
go get github.com/pkg/errors: unexpected status (http://myartifactory:8081/artifactory/api/go/go/github.com/pkg/errors/@v/list): 404 Not Found
```

What I have:

- go v1.11
- artifactory v6.5.9
- GO111MODULE=on and GOPROXY=${ARTIFACTORY_URL}

What I found in the Artifactory remote repo is a goget.html showing a Github page. It seems Artifactory is unable to clone the remote repo from Github but just saved an irrelevant html page. May I ask what's possible reason cause this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is go-remote?

Comment: it's a remote repo for Go in artifactory. A virtual Go repo composed of local Go repo and a remote Go repo.

Comment: @user3273383 please look at the following JFrog knowledge base article - https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/why-does-go-returns-a-404-response-for-some-builds-when-using-remote-repository/

Comment: Thank you @user3273383. I read the same article. In fact, this error happens on some projects with go.mod.

Comment: @user3273383 we will open a Jira issue and handle this issue as soon as possible. If you have any further info which will help reproducing it please share it.

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky Thank you. Looking forwarding to hearing update from the team.

Comment: maybe https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-18320
>>___fix to version 6.7.0

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in v6.7.

[Artifactory 6.7 Release Note](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory6.7)

*Fixed an issue in which under certain circumstances, an Artifactory remote Go repository would cache a goget.html file instead of the corresponding Go module.*